# DataFrame New Column From Existing Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new dataframe column from an existing dataframe column by simply realacing any "/" with an "_" by calling as below

```
def getFileName(security):    
    security = security.replace('/','_')
    return security

data = {'SecName':['BF/A','AB/CD']}
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['SecName'])
dfTest['FileName'] = getFileName(dfTest['SecName'])
dfTest.head() # the "/" is not replaced by "_"

test = 'BF/A'
getFileName(test) # output is "BF_A" as expected
```

Can someone please explain why the new column does not have underscores ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working as expected because `dfTest['SecName']` returns a `pd.Series`, so this line

```py
security = security.replace('/','_')
```

is invoking [pd.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), which replaces any entries in the of `'/'` in the `Series` with `'_'`. What you want is [pd.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
def getFileName(security):    
    security = security.str.replace('/','_')
    return security
```

In the general case where you want to apply a function to each element of a `pd.Series`, use [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to modify the getFileName function as follow:

```
def getFileName(security):    
    security = security.apply(lambda x:x.replace('/','_'))
    return security
```

You apply replace on the whole column but not to each entry within the column. Use the apply function on the pd.Series to obtain the desired result.